# Zabbix MySQL Monitoring error with default template

Tags: mysql, templates, zabbix

I'm using zabbix default MySQL template to monitor. I got those error

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
  7328:20160202:150028.508 In zbx_waitpid()
  7328:20160202:150028.508 zbx_waitpid() exited, status:1
  7328:20160202:150028.508 End of zbx_waitpid():7337
  7328:20160202:150028.508 Run remote command [HOME=/var/lib/zabbix mysqladmin ping | grep -c alive] Result [1] [0]...
  7328:20160202:150028.508 Sending back [0]
```

I can access mysql via command line and already setup .my.cnf in **/var/lib/zabbix** with

```
[client]
user=zabbix
password=zabbix
[mysqladmin]
user=zabbix
password=zabbix
```

Even don't get result with root user.

Comment: Check if mysql is runnig mysqladmin -u root -p status

Answer (score 0):

[image: Helpful image for output]

add the lines : `host=localhost`, and try again

Comment: Thanks for contributing to stackoverflow. Please do not paste screenshots - paste and describe the relevant code/config as text instead.